# Confirm message on browser page close

Tags: javascript

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {return 'Are you shure?';} );
```

How I must do that if user click CANCEL button page will be redirect to http://mypage.com?

Comment: Were they *already* going there? or you want to redirect them to somewhere unexpected?

Comment: If user want close page in brawser, that brawser send confirm message and if they click CANCEL button that page is redirect! No OK button! Sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot change what happens when the user clicks one of the buttons in the dialog.  This is intentional.  Nobody wants to have web sites that mess with your navigation to that level.

Comment: Sorry! 
If user want close page in brawser, that brawser send confirm message and if they click CANCEL button that page is redirect! No OK button!

Comment: Whether it's the OK or cancel button, there's the same restriction.  The only thing that event handler can do is have the user confirm whether they want to proceed with their action or cancel.  What is your use case for this feature?  Maybe there's an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can u do

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure?")
if (answer){
    alert("Bye bye!")
}else{
    alert("Thanks for sticking around!")
}

});
```

i just noticed that it wont prevent them from closing the window but it will show a confirmation when you close it >.<

it must be possible though since stackoverflow is doing it... try writing an answer and then close the windows you'll get a confirm box

Comment: it wont prevent them from closing the window but it will show a confirmation when you close it >.<