# How to show confirm message on close of child window in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a parent window and when I click a link from parent window, the link opens in a new window. **I need to show confirm message on close of child window.(i.e. the opened link )**

```
childWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com","width=400, height=400");
```

I like confirm close for child window. like

```
childWindow.close(function(){var confirmClose=confirm("Are you sure to close ?");
});
```

If the user clicks "OK" of the confirm box then the child window will be closed, else if the user click "Cancel" then the child window will not be closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onbeforeunload` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Comment: Thank you very much . Now I need If the user clicks "OK" of the confirm box then the child window will be closed, else if the user click "Cancel" then the child window will not be closed

Comment: You cannot modify dialog's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To set up a confirm dialogue, add a listener to the `beforeunload` event of the (child)window as demonstrated in [Confirm message on browser page close](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4339028/1048572) and prevent the action eventually.

If you call `childWindow.close()`, the window will get closed instead of hooking a callback function.